# Nginx redirection issue when opening link in new tab

Tags: nginx-config

I have a vue application deployed on windows with Nginx, node.js based backend. There's a button on the webpage which opens the link underneath in a new tab. I have an Nginx file which is not able to redirect the url correctly.

I'm new to Nginx, the nginx.conf was written by a colleague, who's not there anymore. I've pasted the code below.

How should I tackle this issue?

Thanks for ideas and help.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen  81  default_server;
        listen [::]:81  default_server;
        server_name 192.168.1.2;
        
        
        root   "D:\Workspace\build\frontend\dist";
        index  index.html index.htm;
        
        location /socket.io {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:7777;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        
        location /api {
            # a bunch of boilerplate proxy configuration
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:7777;
        }
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:9999;
        }

        error_log  "D:\\Workspace\\build\\nginx\\fe.log";
        access_log "D:\\Workspace\\build\\nginx\\fe-access.log";
    
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two issues here:

1. Nginx's behavior in Windows or rather Windows not sure. Nginx keeps running in the background and doesn't show up in the task manager. Whatever config changes I did and reloaded, it never took effect. So if you're developing/testing/deploying on windows, remember to kill Nginx using "taskkill /F /FI "IMAGENAME eq nginx.exe". Then restart Nginx to reload modified conf file.
2. The location / block. It should be simply written as shown below and it works beautifully, refresh error is solved.

   location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

I'm yet to solve the opening of URL in new tab. It is not being redirected correctly. Will comment/update the answer when I resolve it.

Leaving this answer so that anyone facing the problem finds the solution. The above mentioned Nginx conf works for Vue app with Node.js backend and also having a socket.

Cheers,
Kashyap